# writing to (boost asio) TCP sockets: one by one or all at the same time

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, boost-asio

I have a TCP server and I must send data to many sockets at the same time.
I'm using boost in order to do so.

When I need to send data to multiple sockets, I call on each socket `boost::asio::async_write` with whatever data I want to send.

I was wondering if there will be any difference and advantages in calling `boost::asio::async_write` on one socket and wait for the call back (and then call it on the next socket...)

Comment: If your wait on a asynchronous call then there was no point in making that call asynchronous use `boost::asio::write` if you need to wait.

Comment: I guess the real question behind mine is what happen when we call async write, and what triggers the callback. Does it trigger the callback once the data is sent or once it is received? In the later case writing on different socket at the same time must be more efficient (I guess)

Comment: @ahenderson: Waiting for an event completion does not necessitate blocking for the event completion.  Consider a single threaded server where the write takes a notable amount of time.  A synchronous write would block incoming connections and data; on the other hand, daisy chaining the asynchronous writes would allow for the server to continue accepting incoming connections and data.

Comment: @jules I actually mentioned that in my answer: the callback is triggered once the data has been passed to the operating system (it doesn't mean that the data has actually been sent nor that it has been received)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Waiting for the callback from async_write only introduces a (essentially random) delay, but doesn't give you any benefit at all.

The only exception would be if the underlying protocol doesn't have any congestion control - i.e. when using UDP you would probably want to implement some kind of congestion control in your application, but even then waiting for the async_write callback wouldn't be a good idea (as that just tells you that the data has been passed to the operating system).

But as you are using TCP, waiting for the callback doesn't provide any benefit.

Comment: where does the random delay come from? I guess I don't really understand what's going on when I call multiple async_write on different sockets. Are they queued and process one by one or is there a smarter logic in boost asio

Comment: It's essentially "random" because the async_write callback will be called once the data has been passed to the operating system (which can be almost immediately or take some time when the socket write buffer is full).

Comment: But if the buffer of one socket is full, does that mean that the io service will be locked, or will it try to write in the buffer of another socket if they have been several async_write called (on different sockets)?

Comment: @jules: It will not block. For example, if the write failed because the buffer was full, and the OS returned `EWOULDBLOCK`, `EAGAIN`, or `ERROR_RETRY`, then Asio will push the operation back into the job queue.  This allows the other write operations to run, and the write operation on the previously full socket will eventually be attempted again.  For any non-recoverable errors, the *WriteHandler* will be invoked with the appropriate [Boost.Asio error](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/boost/asio/error.hpp).

Comment: @twsansbury: thanks for that, it's very helpful. One last question: if I use a `std::vector< boost::asio::const_buffer >` when I call async write, do I have to keep the vector until all writes are done or do can I release it as soon as sync_write is called (knowing of course that I manage the underlying boost::asio::const_buffer properly).

Comment: @jules: Should be fine.  The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html) states that Asio may create copies as necessary.  It is also demonstrated in the serialization [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/serialization/connection.hpp).

Answer (score 1):

Be warned I am not a network expert so feel free to comment if I got anything wrong here.

**Asynchronous:**

- **Advantages** of making an asynchronous call is control is returned immediately after the call. So while we are waiting to verify the status of the call we can do other more productive things or yield the CPU. This makes asynchronous system efficient.
- **Disadvantages** are that it's hard to make an asynchronous call. They require no locks and mechanism for communication result of a call. This can be very tricky to implement.

**Synchronous:**

- **Advantages** of making an synchronous call is that they are easier to implement and understand.
- **Disadvantages** are they block until a result is obtained. This can make a system very slow and deadlocks are possible.

Comment: Seems like a good overview.  I would argue that Boost.Asio makes it fairly easy to make asynchronous calls, but I fully agree that  asynchronous programming can be tricky.  One additional disadvantage of asynchronous programming, specifically with a Proactor pattern, is that memory usage may be higher.  The lifespan of a buffer must exceed the duration of a read or write operation, and concurrent operations may require their own buffer.

Comment: @twsansbury I'll add in the insight you just shared. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The *WriteHandler* is runnable when the `async_write` operation either incurs an error or writes all data do the socket.  Thus, issuing multiple asynchronous writes across different sockets may result in speed gains.  However, it requires additional care to properly manage the *buffer*.

- If the buffer is managed by a `shared_ptr`, then simply bind the `shared_ptr` to each *WriteHandler*.
- If the buffer is not managed by a smart pointer, then there needs to be a mechanism to detect when the last *WriteHandler* has been invoked.  Consider storing the count of pending write handlers into a `pending_writes_` variable, and having each *WriteHandler* decrement `pending_writes_`.  Once `pending_writes_` reaches zero, the buffer can be reused for other operations.  To serialize modifications to `pending_writes_`, wrap each of the *WriteHandlers* in a [`strand`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html).